# How to connect DC++ while being behind a HTTP proxy server

Tags: proxy, tunnel, dc++

My computer running windows 7 is connected to my college's LAN network which is behind a HTTP proxy server and requires basic authentication.I want to connect my DC++(0.799) to public hubs and download but i can't since their is no HTTP proxy option in DC++.I tried using proxifier but using it i could only connect to those hubs.DC++ was unable to search,view file lists of users or download anything when I try to get file list of any user, it tries to connect and after some time says connection failed. Is their any other way to connect or is their any other way to connect to public DC hubs via any other application i.e is their any other similar apllication.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP proxy is the least of your problems. In addition to the HTTP proxy, your computer is most likely behind a NAT with a private IP address. You must forward ports to your computer to get connected to a hub, get search results and download files. You can [proxify](https://proxify.com/) HTTP, and you will be able to download hub lists. You need a SOCKS5 proxy, not a HTTP proxy, to enable the rest. There is an option for that in DC++.

Don't confuse connecting to a public hub with getting public hub lists. In other words, you can connect to a public hub (or private one), provided that you have properly forwarded ports, even without getting a public hub list.

- To download public hub lists in DC++: You need HTTP and TCP.
- To send search queries in DC++: You need UDP.
- To get search results in DC++: You need UDP.
- To download files in DC++: You need TCP.
- To download user file lists in DC++: You need TCP.
- You need to forward ports if you're behind a NAT, or use a SOCKS5
  proxy.